# Need a batch script that will extract all files inside a zipped file inside a single large zipped file

Tags: batch-file, zip, batch-processing, 7zip

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
giantzippedfile.zip
  0.zip
    file_0
  1.zip
    file_1
  ...
```

And I want to run a script that will leave just the file_i's.

I was hoping to use something like this:

```
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I"
)
```

But this just gives me all the i.zip instead of file_i that I want. And the script seems to be idempotent; running it a second time doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

(untested) Try:

```
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I"
    rem change to the directory, extract zips, delete them and change back
    pushd "%%~dpI"
    for /F %%z IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"." "%%z"
        del "%%z"
    )
    popd
)
```